# Настройка PhpStorm + XDebug

Tags: битрикс, phpstorm, xdebug

Доброго времени суток.

Вот наконец решил разобраться и настроить PhpStorm + XDebug. 
Всю настройку php я произвел по аналогии, как указано вот тут: http://bb3x.ru/blog/otladka-s-podderzhkoy-xdebug-i-phpstorm-na-primere-sayta-1s-bitriks/#comment-17012

В итоге меня перекидывает на страницу

```
http://192.168.16.52:8888/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=12732
```

И больше никаких действий, да и в самом шторме в разделе отладки появляется предупреждение:

> Warning for incoming connection
> withide key ’12732′

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема, чего я не так сделал.

Comment: Если не секрет, зачем вам оно нужно?

Comment: Попробуйте выставить галочки ``Force break at the first line when no path mapping specified`` и ``Force break at the first line when a script is outside the project``.

А еще, для Chrome, есть очень удобное расширение [Xdebug helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc).

Плюс, почитайте доки на сайте phpStorm: [Debugging PHP Applications](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/debugging-php-applications.html)

Answer (score 0):

PhpStorm отлично работает с отладчиком xDebug, если установить плагин для браузера xDebug helper. При этом появляется значок жука, кликнув по которому можно включить отладку страницы. Потом в PhpStorm начать кнопку, которая отвечает за прослушивание входящих сообщений (Телефон с жуком) и все, если ваш сервер настроен на работу с xDebug, то вы сразу же готовы к отладке.